# C++ POSIX (or Linux specific) and WIN32 calls for artificially changing a file's creation date

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, posix, portability

To start: My code depends on Boost.

I need to alter file creation dates to inject errors into my unit tests.

Is there a portable way, either in the STL, or C++ standard libraries, or boost(::filesystem), to do this ? If not does anyone know of a good simple C++ header-only (or very simple) abstraction that will complement what is in boost /STL/STD ?

If not I require the headers / function names / data structures for artificially changing the creation date of a file post-creation on windows and Linux (or a more unix-wide portable solution).

Any pointers will help.

Comment: you need creation date or modified date?

Comment: I needed creation date, i'm building a windows registry-esque key-object serialization mechanism for protocol buffer objects on the filesystem. It has a two phase commit, so I need to modify creation date to corrupt a partial two phase commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX solution would be [`utimes`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7990989775/xsh/utimes.html).

```
#include <sys/time.h>

int utimes(const char *filename, const struct timeval times[2]);
```

The win32 solution would be [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724933.aspx).